# Automatically update Plotly React Chart when data changes

Tags: reactjs, plotly.js

The below react code renders a chart that is updated with additional data when a button is pressed. The count state is passed into the BarChart function as a prop. However, the chart does not automatically update when the data changes. How can this be achieved?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';
function main() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState([1,2,3]);
  return(
    <>
    <BarChart value={count}/>
    <button onClick={() => setCount([...count, 123])}/>
    </>
  )
}

const BarChart = (count) => {

    return (
        <div>
        <Plot
            data={[
                {type: 'scatter',
                x: ['one','two','three'],
                y: count,
                marker: {color: 'red'}
                }]}
            layout={{width: 1000, height: 500, title: "hello"}}
            
        />
    </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code doesn't affect on plot data. First of all you can't pass variable to children component in that way. You should do it via props. It is an object which stores the value of attributes of a tag and work similar to the HTML attributes. I revrited your code to make it more readable.

```js
const App = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState([1, 2, 3]);
    return (
        <>
            <BarChart value={count} />
            <button
                onClick={() =>
                    setCount([...count, count.at(count.length - 1) + 1])
                }
            >
                Update
            </button>
        </>
    );
};
```

If you click on `Update` button new item will be pushed to it's end. Next the count array is passed to `BarChart` component as `value` attribute.

If you interact with plot, all previous information will be lost. Solution for this is storing plot data in state variable. Initial `x` & `y` data are gathered from passed `count` variable (`props.value`) to plot component.

```js
const BarChart = (props) => {
    const [settings, updateSettings] = useState({
        data: [
            {
                x: props.value,
                y: props.value,
                type: 'scatter',
                marker: { color: 'red' },
            },
        ],
        layout: { width: '100%', height: 500, title: 'hello' },
        frames: {},
        config: {},
    });
    useEffect(() => {
        updateSettings((settings) => ({
            ...settings,
            data: [{ ...settings.data[0], y: props.value, x: props.value }],
        }));
    }, [props.value]);
    return (
        <div>
            <Plot data={settings.data} layout={settings.layout} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

If `count` variable in parent component has been changed, it will activate update event in children component (`componentDidUpdate() or useEffect()`). In this case I used `useEffect()`. Hook will execute always if `props.value` value has been changed. Then it will update data arrays from gathered data and re-render plot with new data.